# ASP.NET Automatically redirect user to exit when session timeout ends

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to automatically redirect the user to logout when their session expires. Because I log when the user logs out. I made this redirect using javascript, do you think this approach makes sense?
Or does it make sense to check it every 1 minute in the javascript function below?

`web.config`:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20"></sessionState>
```

Javascript :

```
//SESSION TIMEOUT CONTROL
var sessionTimeoutInMinutes = 18; 
var lastInteractionTime = new Date().getTime();

function resetInteractionTime() {
    lastInteractionTime = new Date().getTime();
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", resetInteractionTime);
document.addEventListener("keydown", resetInteractionTime);
document.addEventListener("click", resetInteractionTime);


var checkUserActivity = setInterval(function () {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    var elapsedTime = (currentTime - lastInteractionTime) / 1000; 

    if (elapsedTime > sessionTimeoutInMinutes * 60) {
        window.location.href = "/Login/LogOut"; 
        clearInterval(checkUserActivity); 
    }
}, 60000);
```